# How to trigger a select box to open when a link is pressed. (HTML/iPhone/Javascript)

Tags: javascript, iphone, html, select, drop-down-menu

Basically, I'm building a mobile site with LOTS of content. I have a header, then a menu with three buttons that I need to open select menus so that the iPhone's select wheel will appear. Any ideas? So far my searching says not possible...

Answer (score 1):

two ideas spring to mind.

1. Use CSS style properties to set the select tags to Display:none. Use javascript to change to display:block when the button is pressed.
2. Have a place holder div and inject the select tag using .innerHTML.

In both cases you will need to set the focus to the appropriate select tag.